# Neovim: mapping A-b

Tags: neovim

I am trying to map `<A-b>` to `<C-left>` in insert mode in neovim. When I press `<A-b>` it just inserts the character 0, but when I start neovim with --clean (so all configurations are ignored), it works as expected, and the cursor moves one word backwards. I use alacritty, but it was the same in other terminals like kitty too. This is what I use to remap: `vim.keymap.set('i', '<A-b>', '<C-left>')`. Output of `:verbose map <A-b>` is `No mapping found`. It's the same even if I set the keybind with `:inoremap <A-b> <C-left>` inside neovim after everything has loaded.

Edit: There was a conflict with the auto-pairs plugin. After I disabled it, the keybinding worked as it should.

Comment: Could you tell us what is the result of the following command: `:verbose map <A-b>`?

Comment: Could you tell us which command do you use to map `<A-b>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your mapping is in conflict with a plugin mapping.

You can try two things

1. Make sure your mapping is not remapped
2. Verify that your mapping is not overriden

```
:verbose map <A-b>
```

### Remapping:

If you map `<A-b>` to `<C-left>` with:

```
imap <A-b> <C-left>
```

But that `<C-left>` is mapped by a plugin to `0` then `<A-b>` is mapped to `0`.

The solution could be to use `inoremap` instead

```
inoremap <A-b> <C-left>
```

### Overridden

If you map in `.vimrc` your mapping can be overridden by a plugin code that is executed later.

You can analyze the situation with the following command:

```
verbose map <A-b>
```

If your mapping is overridden you could use the following command to make your mapping win:

```
augroup mymapping
  autocmd VimEnter * inoremap <A-b> <C-left>
augroup END
```